# Why is the format parameter for a HyperlinkedIdentityField page set to "api" when I have explicitly defined it as html in serializers.py

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use a HyperlinkedIdentityField to display a link for a field within a serializer. The link is correct on the except for the suffix of `?format=api` when it should be `?format=html`.

I'm using a DefaultRouter for myapplication/urls.py, this might be the cause of my problems, but I don't what to do in order to solve the problem

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):      
  owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
  highlight = 
  serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='snippet-highlight', 
    format='html')
```

And in the browser, the JSON format of a model previously created is displayed as:

```
{
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/1/?format=api",
    "id": 1,
    "highlight": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/1/highlight/?format=api",
    "owner": "admin",
}
```

When the link is clicked, the user is linked to a 404 error, however, if the link is manually updated to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/1/?format=html` everything is displayed as expected